# System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNavigatingTo' of undefined

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

My nativescript application runs successfully in first run without any error, but when I save any file without any change, or small changes my app crashes whith below information.

```html
08-24 13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) 08-24 13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime: at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116) 08-24 13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime:
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996) 08-24 13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983) 08-24 13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967) 08-24
13:32:36.684 3595 3595 E AndroidRuntime: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959) System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException: System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed System.err: System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNavigatingTo'
of undefined System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js, line: 262, column: 36 System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err: Frame: function:'FrameBase._onNavigatingTo',
file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 262, column: 37 System.err: Frame: function:'FrameBase.performNavigation', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js',
line: 234, column: 14 System.err: Frame: function:'FrameBase._processNextNavigationEntry', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 227, column: 22 System.err: Frame: function:'Frame._processNextNavigationEntry',
file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 138, column: 58 System.err: Frame: function:'Frame._onAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
line: 114, column: 14 System.err: Frame: function:'AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.TekmoTs/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 38, column: 27 System.err: System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native
Method) System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116) System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996) System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983) System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
System.err: at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959) System.err: at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_frame_32_36_AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow(Object_frame_32_36_AttachListener.java:17) System.err: at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18358)
System.err: at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397) System.err: at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404) System.err: at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
System.err: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761) System.err: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460) System.err: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183) System.err:
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949) System.err: at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761) System.err: at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696) System.err: at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

the app-root.xml file's content is as below:

```html
<Frame defaultPage="views/contact-us/contact-us">
</Frame>
```

and file stucture is as below:

`├───app
│   ├───App_Resources
│   │   ├───Android
│   │   └───iOS
│   └───views
│       ├───about
│       ├───contact-us
│       └───home
├───hooks
...`

the contact-us.xml file's content is also is as below:

`<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatedTo">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Contact us by submitting a message below." textWrap="true" />

            <TextField hint="Enter a subject..." />

            <TextView hint="Enter a Message..."/> 
            <Button text="Submit" tap="onTap" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>`

not: if I stop app with **ctrl+c** and y then restart my app with **tns run android** it runs successfully without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with completely deleting platforms folder and rerun the app with **tns run android**.

Ok, I found the real error causing this, error happen whenever I change my app-root.xml'e defaultPage attribute to another page. I think this is an Issue with nativescript watch.

changing the app-root.xml's defaultPage attribute to another page while app is running is crashing the app.